# How to run JavaScript function in before_save filter to replace some value before saving into database?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, before-save

I have categoried, which user choose. If user choose 'Auto' I need to replace it with result, what gives me my JavaScript function - setting default browser language.

Here is JavaScript example, of JS function - http://fiddle.jshell.net/xCgsb/

And here is my before_save filter in Website model:

```
before_save :auto_language

def create
 website = current_user.websites.new params[:website]
 if @website.language == "Auto"
  @website.language = request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'].scan(/^[a-z]{2}/).first
 end
...
#error
undefined local variable or method `request' for #<Website:0x244e1b0>
```

Can someone help me with this trouble ? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be using Javascript to set up your default locale.

Take a look at this:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-the-locale-from-the-client-supplied-information

They use Ruby to detect the locale

```
def set_locale
   logger.debug "* Accept-Language: #{request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']}"
   I18n.locale = extract_locale_from_accept_language_header
   logger.debug "* Locale set to '#{I18n.locale}'"
end  

private

def extract_locale_from_accept_language_header
    request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'].scan(/^[a-z]{2}/).first
end
```

If you want to get the full language, you can use a switch case:

```
def full_language_name(lang) 
  case lang
    when 'ru'
      return 'Russian'
    when 'en'
      return 'English'
    when 'fr'
      return 'French'
    else
      return 'English'
end
```

The 'else' case is the default behavior if none of these conditions has been verified.
The keyword 'return' is optional.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't need to use localization, I just need put correct website(Model) language into database - default browser language if user chooses Auto.

Comment: Well, this line:
request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'].scan(/^[a-z]{2}/).first
Will return the two letters of the navigator's language

Comment: Oh, sorry. I'm fool a little bit... Thanks.

Comment: one more thing - I need full language name. Is it possible ?

Comment: Errrh I don't think its possible... the line `request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']` returns `fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4` for my computer, just the locale and the 'country language'

Comment: MrYoshiji, maybe I should add some method, which will be returning FULL language, what do you think ?

Comment: Gives me `undefined method request` when using it i before filter

Comment: The request cannot be seen in the Model. Use request.env in the controller, before creating/setting the locale of your object Website.

Comment: What do you think I need to do ? Find some gem ?

Comment: No, you need to set the language in a controller. Like if you have an action for create and update your Model Website, use it there. (example: `if params[:website][:language] == 'Auto' [...]` )

Comment: I see what you try to do here but it can't work. The model cannot have access to the requests (respecting the MVC). You have to find a workaround, like set the locale in the controller when you create / update a Website.

Comment: In create action ? Like this (look up)?

Comment: Yes ! Exactly ! But it will set le language with the two letters, not the full name. You can create a method, a switch-case between few languages (fr, en, ru, etc...) that will return the full name of the language. And don't forget to set it in the update action too! ;)

Comment: Last question: what rails function I need to use to replace `ru` into `russian` and etc ?

Comment: Thanks. I found it. You helped very much. Thanks, again.